# Is it possible to create/manage a user from inside and Oracle APEX application?

Tags: oracle, frontend, oracle-apex

I developed an application in APEX for some engineers in my company to use, but twice a week or so they call my desk asking me to add another user.  Is there any way to build a user creation page into an APEX application so that it can be handled entirely by users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a new user outside of the APEX environment you can use PL/SQL. Make sure, that you set the security group to the workspace-id for which the new user will be created. Run this statement as database system user
See the code snipped below:

```
  declare
    l_workspace_id number;
    l_group_id     number;
  begin
    [...]
    l_workspace_id := apex_util.find_security_group_id('Your Workspace Name');

    apex_util.set_security_group_id(l_workspace_id);

    l_group_id := apex_util.get_group_id('Your User-Group');

    apex_util.create_user(p_user_name           => 'Your User-Name',
                          p_email_address       => 'eMail Address',
                          p_first_name          => '...',
                          p_last_name           => '...',
                          p_default_date_format => '...',
                          p_web_password        => '...',
                          p_group_ids           => l_group_id,  
                          p_default_schema      => '...');

    [...]
  end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  If you want to create an APEX user, you can use the [`APEX_UTIL.CREATE_USER` procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_util.htm#BABCFBGG).

Depending on the situation, it would be a bit more common to create your own `user` table, a custom authentication routine, and then modify your application to use that custom authentication routine rather than relying on APEX users.  This tends to make it easier to manage more complicated permissions (e.g. applications that support multiple different roles) or to integrate with other authentication providers like LDAP/ Active Directory.

Comment: I'd like to mention that you cannot outright use `apex_util.create_user` as a simple end user. It requires administrative privileges in the database. It'd be a bad idea as you could just create a full on workspace admin. Given the rights, it'd also be possible to alter other users and their password. I'm quite sure it doesn't work out of the box that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass security mesure.
You can create a oracle job with apex_util.create_user .
On button you can put process that start job.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).